# Access table in .dbf file + Oracle

Tags: windows, oracle11g, dbf

I am trying to access a table which is present in the .dbf in the local drive.

This was my latest attempt, got this from another site

```
select at.owner || '.' || at.table_name table_name,
       ddf.file_name
    from   all_tables at,
            dba_extents de,
            dba_data_files ddf
    where  at.owner = de.owner
    and    at.table_name = de.segment_name
    and at.table_name = "Table1"    and    de.file_id = ddf.file_id
    order  by table_name
```

I am using Oracle 11.2 in Windows 2003.

I checked and verified that the .dbf is in "READ WRITE" mode.

How can I access the table in the .dbf file?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/167820/0/

Please refer to this URL the solution for your question is already discussed in this forum..

Comment: That was the site I referred to earlier and I did not get the required ouput. I got the ouput record not found

Comment: Please don't just paste links to potential answers. Add a short summary of the solution and quotes relevant to consecutive steps of the solution.